# How to only get one column output for Measure-Object Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, select-object, line-count, measure-object

I'm trying to get the line count of a csv file. I ran this code to get it:

```
$csvPath = "some.csv"
$lineCount = "linecount.csv"
Import-Csv $csvPath | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Measure-Object | Export-CSV $lineCount -NoTypeInformation
```

This is the output I get in `linecount.csv`:

```
"Count","Average","Sum","Maximum","Minimum","Property"
"100",,,,,
```

This is my desired output:

```
"Count"
"100"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Change `Import-Csv` to `Get-Content`. I wouldn't recommend this method for a very large file tho, [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76419378/15339544) would be the more efficient and recommended one.

Comment: Why are you skipping the first record with `Select-Object -Skip 1`? `Import-Csv` already eats the header, so your "line count" will be off by (at least) 2

Comment: You're right, Mathias! Thank you. I removed the `-Skip 1` and it's outputting correctly the number after I reviewed the line count in the CSV and in the line count report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **select a *subset* of the properties from an object / each object in a collection**, pipe them to **[`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)** and pass the property names of interest to the **`-Property` parameter**.

Therefore, to get only the `Count` property (using a simplified example):

```bash
# To pass *multiple* property names, separate them with ","
# Since -Property is the first positional parameter, you may omit its name.
1..10 | Measure-Object | Select-Object -Property Count
```

Note:

- For each input object, `Select-Object` outputs a [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instance that contains the specified properties.<sup>[1]</sup>
- In addition to selecting existing properties as-is, you **may define [*calculated* properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties)**, which can be used to define properties with values *derived* from the input objects' property values, to *rename* properties, or to add entirely new properties.
- If you pipe the above to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), you'll get the desired CSV output; to verify this *in memory*, pipe to [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) instead.
- By contrast, if you merely want the *value* of the `Count` property (rather than an *object* with a `Count` property), you can use `-ExpandProperty` instead of `-Property` or pipe to `| ForEach-Object Count` instead; however the following is more concise and efficient:<sup>[2]</sup>

  ```bash
  (1..10 | Measure-Object).Count   # -> 10
  ```

---

As for you **what you're counting**:

- If you want to determine the **the number of data *lines*** in your input CSV files - excluding the header line, use ***plain-text* processing** via [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) instead of [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)

  ```bash
  Get-Content $csvPath | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Measure-Object | 
    Select-Object Count | Export-CSV $lineCount -NoTypeInformation
  ```

  - **Caveats:**

    - CSV *rows* can span more than *line*, so this method will only report the correct count if all rows, including the header row, occupy exactly one line each (while that is *typical*, it isn't *guaranteed*).
    - As Santiago points out, this method can perform poorly with large input files, in which case you're better off using the approach shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76419378/15339544).
- If you want **the number of data *rows*** in your input CSV file, `Import-Csv` is *all* you need: no need for `Select-Object -Skip 1`, because what `Import-Object` returns are objects representing just the *data* rows - the header information is "baked into" each such object, in the form of the object's *property names*:

  ```bash
  Import-Csv $csvPath | Measure-Object | 
    Select-Object Count | Export-CSV $lineCount -NoTypeInformation
  ```

  - **Note:**

    - While this is the *correct and robust* way to count data rows in a CSV file, it is even slower than the `Get-Content` method.

---

<sup>[1] In an effort to reflect the type of the objects that the properties were taken from, the output objects are assigned an additional type name, via PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763), formed by prepending `Selected.` to the full type name of the input objects. In this example: `Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo`. This ETS type name surfaces when you pass such instances to [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member), for instance, and also as the first entry of the [instrinsic `.pstypenames` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#type-information) value and in the type-identifying comment added to CSV output by `Export-Csv` / `ConvertTo-Csv` if `-NoTypeInformation` is *not* used in *Windows PowerShell* / if `-IncludeTypeInformation` *is* used in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).</sup>

<sup>[2] This even works with *multiple* input objects, courtesy of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature. However, this requires collecting all input objects in memory, up front. While this generally won't be a problem, it could be with large input collections
where processing the property values *one by one* must be performed; in that case, use the `Select-Object` or `ForEach-Object` techniques.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation! I'm still learning Powershell so this was really insightful and educational.

Comment: Another way would be to specify the `Count` member. `(1..10 | Measure-Object).Count`

Comment: Thanks, @lit - yes, if you want only the _value_ of the `.Count` property , that's the best approach. Note that the premise of the question is to get an _object with a `.Count` property_; however, I've added the `(...).Count` technique to the answer as well, along with an explanation of how it differs.